# Firestore rules failing with custom claims in token

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a 'step up' system where a user confirms a code and is granted additional privileges in the form of claims. Upon the token update, the iOS client refreshes the token and I have confirmed the claims now exist.

However, for some reason, the below rules often, but not always, fail. In particular setting a value to

```
/databases/(default)/documents/users/z4enRpOt3TXwjUkyD7qsShXTRMF3/accounts/06f92564-56f0-4641-9aaa-97e6a5ce3044
```

.. fails very regularly.

Rules below:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function notAnonymous() {
      return request.auth.uid != null
    }

    function signedIn(uid) {
      return request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == uid;
    }

    function deviceApproved(uid) {
      return signedIn(uid) && request.auth.token.deviceApproved == true;
    }

    function deviceOwner(uid) {
      return signedIn(uid) && deviceApproved(uid) && request.auth.token.ownershipApproved == true;
    }

    match /settings/public {
      allow read;
    }

    match /stocks/{stockId} {
      allow read: if notAnonymous();
    }

    match /bonds/{bondId} {
      allow read: if notAnonymous();
    }

    match /users/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if signedIn(uid);

      match /device/token {
        allow read, write: if signedIn(uid)
      }

      match /accounts/{accountId=**} {
        allow read: if deviceApproved(uid);
        allow write: if deviceOwner(uid);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

I have tried many different combinations of the rules but without success.

Not sure if it has any relation, but the collection /accounts/ does not exist until the attempted write. However in my understanding the rule should allow the creation of the document.

Code being used to set the value is below. I am using RxSwift, but it's just wrapping the standard set.

```
func savePending(account: Account) -> Observable<Account> {
    guard let userKey = account.userKey else { return Observable.error(AuthError.failedGettingUser) }
    let key = account.key ?? UUID().uuidString.lowercased()

    return Firestore.firestore()
        .collection("users").document(userKey)
        .collection("accounts").document(key)
        .rx.set(account.asDictionary())
        .debug()
        .flatMapLatest({ () -> Observable<Account> in
            return Observable.just(account)
        })
        .catchError({ (error) -> Observable<Account> in
            print(error)
            throw error
        })
}
```